# Unable to print string with jquery - when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to render a string on the DOM when the user pushes a button.

This is the HTML code:

```
<p>
    <h1 class="text-center" id="notif">
    </h1>
</p>
```

And this is the portion of the script:

```
$("#btn_My").click(function(e) {
    $("#notif").html("Hello World!");
```

When the button is clicked, a new paragraph is visible in the rendered page, but the string is not inside the rendered view.

When I check the source code of the page, this is what I get:

```
<p>
</p>
<h1 class="text-center" id="notif" style="display: none;">Hello World!</h1>
<p></p>
```

Why is this happening and how will I manage to render it properly?

Comment: That's because a paragraph can't contain a heading. It's invalid HTML that the browser is trying to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is normal behavior. Because the implementation is wrong.** :(

The reason is that tag `P` is an `inline` element that cannot contain `block` elements, as is the case with tag `H1`.

Change `P` to `DIV`.

See as example: https://jsfiddle.net/ty0uswrm/

Read this documentation: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an h3 into a paragraph. It's impossible to determine what correct render is for you, however, I assume that you have closed the function for click, like this:

```
$("#btn_My").click(function(e) {
    $("#notif").html("Hello World!");
}
```

The HTML will be modified even before you click on your button, because it is invalid in the form you have created. The cause is that browsers will automatically close an unclosed inline element when they encounter a heading.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
<span id="notif" class="h1"></span>
</p>
```

You can use *span* instead of *h1* and the desired bootstrap header class along with it.
Or, get rid of the *p* like this

```
<span id="notif" class="h1"></span>
```